# Error while running mysql_upgrade

Tags: mysql-8.0

Recently upgraded Mysql from 8.0.20 to 8.0.28 ( removed the older rpms and installed newer ones)
and started Mysqld in RHEL7. All seems good except that I see below error when trying to run mysql_upgrade

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
> what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid   Aborted (core
> dumped)

I know from mysql 8 onwards we dont need to run mysql_upgrade explicitly as the mysql service while starting takes care of the upgrade. But why am I getting a strange error.

I had run mysql_upgrade in mysql 8 versions before and never faced this error. Can i consider the mysql upgrade successful or is this related to any other dependent package?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try -f to force execution?

Comment: Hi Jesus.. I tried that with --force and same error

Comment: I am really not familiar with that error and from what I can see online it doesn't seem to be something common. My guess is an issue with the installation. Error is not instance/sql engine related, that's definitely code

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 8.0.16, mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server